# How to iterate through a map of nested maps using recursion?

Tags: c++

I have nested maps and I need to iterate through each level to print all the values.

This map is to show you an example of a problem that I am trying to solve using `recursion`.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    std::map<std::string, VariableContainer> myMap;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        VariableContainer var;
        var.variables["A" + std::to_string(i)];

        if (i == 1) {
            VariableContainer childVar;
            for (int j = 1; j < 3; ++j) {
               childVar.variables["X_" + std::to_string(j)];
            }
            var.variables.emplace("B" + std::to_string(i), childVar);
        }
        var.variables["C" + std::to_string(i)];
        myMap.emplace("Node_" + std::to_string(i), var);
    }

    for (auto& var : myMap) {
        std::cout << "var: "<< var.first << std::endl;
        if (var.second.variables.size()>0) {
            for (auto& child : var.second.variables) {
                std::cout << " child: "<< child.first << std::endl;
                if (child.second.variables.size()>0) {
                    for (auto& subChild : child.second.variables) {
                        std::cout << "  subChild: "<< subChild.first << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
var: Node_0
 child: A0
 child: C0
var: Node_1
 child: A1
 child: B1
  subChild: X_1
  subChild: X_2
 child: C1
var: Node_2
 child: A2
 child: C2
```

But I need to get the output in the following structure:  `node + "." + child + "." + subChild + "." + nsubChilds`

```
Node_0.A0
Node_0.C0
Node_1.A1
Node_1.B1.X_1
Node_1.B1.X_2
Node_1.C1
Node_2.A2
Node_2.C2
```

This is the `VariableContainer.h`

```
#ifndef VARIABLECONTAINER_H
#define VARIABLECONTAINER_H

#include <map>
#include <string>

class VariableContainer
{
public:
    VariableContainer() {}
    std::map<std::string, VariableContainer> variables;
};

#endif // VARIABLECONTAINER_H
```

I could have maps nested within other maps, something like a branch. I think that using recursion is a good solution since the number of nested maps is different on each execution of the program.

For example, I could have something like this: `Node_1.B1.X_1.Y_1.Z_1`

I tried the following recursive function but I'm not getting the desired output.

```
void MainWindow::showMap(std::map<std::string, VariableContainer> &map) {
    for (auto& var : map) {
        std::cout << "var: "<< var.first << std::endl;
        if (var.second.variables.size() > 0) {
            showMap(var.second.variables);
        }
    }
}
```

Any Idea or suggestion to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the branch name to the function `showMap()`.

e.g.

```cpp
class VariableContainer
{
public:
    VariableContainer() {}
    std::map<std::string, VariableContainer> variables;
};

void showMap(
    const std::string &BranchName,  //I think this is necessary
    const std::map<std::string, VariableContainer> &map
)
{
    for( const auto &var : map )
    {
        std::string VarName = BranchName + var.first;
        if( var.second.variables.empty() )  //if leaf
        {   std::cout << VarName << std::endl;  }
        else
        {   showMap( VarName+".", var.second.variables );   }
    }
}

inline void showMap( const std::map<std::string, VariableContainer> &map )
{   showMap( "", map ); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, VariableContainer> Root;
    {//construct the test data
        {
            auto &Node_0 = Root["Node_0"].variables;
            Node_0["A0"];
            Node_0["C0"];
        }
        {
            auto &Node_1 = Root["Node_1"].variables;
            Node_1["A1"];
            auto &B1 = Node_1["B1"].variables;
            B1["X_1"];
            B1["X_2"];
        }
        {
            auto &Node_2 = Root["Node_2"].variables;
            Node_2["A2"];
            Node_2["C2"];
        }
    }

    showMap( Root );
    return 0;
}
```